# Cannot INSERT date with prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server, date, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a multi-row INSERT for each day of a given month/year.

If the loop runs just once, everything works as expected. If it runs 2 or more times, it throws the below error:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with date (SQLExecute[206] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260)

It also works if I don't prepare the date. I'm at a loss... am I doing something wrong? This is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO scp.schedule
    (record_create_date, associate_id, scheduled_date, shift_id, is_weekend)
    VALUES ";

for ($day_count = 1; $day_count <= $days_month; $day_count++)
{
    $day_count = sprintf("%02d", $day_count);

    $full_date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day_count;

    // Check if date is weekend
    $weekend = (date("N", strtotime($full_date)) < 6) ? 0 : 1;

    $query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $associate["associate_id"];
    $params[] = $full_date;
    $params[] = $shifts[0]["shift_id"];
    $params[] = $weekend;
}

// Remove the last comma and space
$query = substr($query, 0, -2);

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

I am using SQL server version 12+ and PHP version 7+. The column type in the DB is DATE.

**EDIT:**

This works

```
INSERT INTO scp.schedule 
    (record_create_date, associate_id, 
     scheduled_date, shift_id, is_weekend) 
VALUES (GETDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This does not

```
INSERT INTO scp.schedule 
    (record_create_date, associate_id, 
     scheduled_date, shift_id, is_weekend) 
VALUES (GETDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?), 
       (GETDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Some tests and the errors they throw. I've also tried using `'?'`.

```
$query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, DATEFROMPARTS(?, ?, ?), ?, ?), ";
// Also tried intval() and casting to int
$params[] = $year;
$params[] = $month;
$params[] = $day_count;
```

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int (SQLExecute[206] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260)

```
$query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, CONVERT(date, ?), ?, ?), ";
```

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 529 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Explicit conversion from data type text to date is not allowed. (SQLExecute[529] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260)

Comment: For those of us that cannot be bothered to work out what the query would look like, can you add the result of an `echo $query;` to your question so we can see what you are actually trying to run as the query

Comment: What does `$full_date` look like? Remember `DATE` columns are not `DATETIME` columns.

Comment: @RiggsFolly edited the post

Comment: @delboy1978uk `$full_date` looks like "2018-10-01"

Comment: You don't have enough values in `$params` to satisfy all the `?` in the query

Comment: @Nick edited again, my bad

Comment: Are you using `$params` elsewhere? What happens if you put `$params = array();` before the loop?

Comment: I'm not using it elsewhere, no, and I doubt initializing it will have any impact as it already works when the loop runs only once. EDIT: tried, no change

Answer (score 1):

You may try to avoid passing strings as values for date field in SQL Server using [DATEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) T-SQL functions.

```
<?
$query = "INSERT INTO scp.schedule
    (record_create_date, associate_id, scheduled_date, shift_id, is_weekend)
    VALUES ";

for ($day_count = 1; $day_count <= $days_month; $day_count++) {
    $day       = $day_count;
    $day_count = sprintf("%02d", $day_count);
    $full_date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day_count;

    // Check if date is weekend
    $weekend = (date("N", strtotime($full_date)) < 6) ? 0 : 1;

    # Using DATETIMEFROMPARTS
    $query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, DATEFROMPARTS(?, ?, ?), ?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $associate["associate_id"];
    $params[] = $year;
    $params[] = $month;
    $params[] = $day;
    $params[] = $shifts[0]["shift_id"];
    $params[] = $weekend;

    # Using CONVERT
    /*
    $query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, CONVERT(date, ?), ?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $associate["associate_id"];
    $params[] = $full_date;
    $params[] = $shifts[0]["shift_id"];
    $params[] = $weekend;
    */
}

// Remove the last comma and space
$query = substr($query, 0, -2);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

?>
```

If it is not necessery to insert all days in one statement, you may consider to prepare your statement once and execute it in every iteration.
Then, if error occures, you will know what values are causing problem.

Comment: I tried `DATEFROMPARTS()` since my column is `DATE` and now I'm getting a different error: text is incompatible with int. I even tried to use `intval()` on `$year, $month, $day`, same thing. I tried the `CONVERT/CAST` option before but I don't remember the error, I'll give it another try

Comment: @IcedAnt Can you echo and post here $year, $month, $day - there can be some unexpected values? Thanks.

Comment: I can, but it's unlikely, since `$query .= "(GETDATE(), ?, '" . $full_date . "', ?,?), ";` works fine

Comment: `echo $year . $month . $day_count . " ";` 20181001 20181002 20181003 20181004 20181005 20181006 20181007 20181008 20181009 20181010 20181011 20181012 20181013 20181014 20181015 20181016 20181017 20181018 20181019 20181020 20181021 20181022 20181023 20181024 20181025 20181026 20181027 20181028 20181029 20181030 20181031

Comment: I've already tried, it works for one iteration but not for 2 or more. This field is definitely the issue as the query works fine when I am not preparing `$full_date`

Comment: @IcedAnt Is it possible, when you use DATEFROMPARTS, another column values to be the reason for string to int error?

Comment: I don't think so, wouldn't I get the same error when I don't prepare `$full_date` if that was the case?

Comment: @IcedAnt You are right. Your code looks correct, but there is something strange, that's way I want to check the obvious things.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I think I'll try to prepare once and execute in every iteration as you suggested but I need to do quite a bit of refactoring first.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `trim` instead of `substr`.

```
$query = trim(trim($query), ',');
```

The inner `trim` will remove `space` and outer `trim` will remove `,`

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? `substr` works fine, what is the point in using `trim`?

Comment: As you said that it is working fine for single record, it means that there is nothing wrong with the query. So, only thing that can be causing issue is substr.
You are right, there seems to be nothing wrong with substr but just give it a try please.

Comment: I fail to see how `substr` could have a different result if the loop runs more than once... in any case, it will just remove the last 2 characters which will always be a comma and a space. Can you explain?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any different result but trim time complexity is lower than that of substr.